# How to stop logging in eventconsumer.log?

Tags: java, logging, aem

Is there way to disable logging into eventconsumer.log in cq5?

I just do not need this log.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this log comes OOTB with CQ. Which version of CQ are you using ? If it is custom log then you can go to felix console and check for logger in configuration. Or check HOST:PORT/system/console/slinglog and configure your log files there. If it is getting deployed though code then you need to remove custom logger from code.

Yogesh

Comment: I use CQ  version 5.5